# <a> not styling inside <li> tag, displaying invalid property value when I inspect element for CSS values

Tags: html, css

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. But my  styling does not show at all, and instead presents me with 'invalid property value' for all assigned values.

**Here is the HTML and CSS:**

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <img style="width: 40%" src="https://i.imgur.com/wNLc5fC.jpg">
  <div>
    <h2>Digital Assets For Creative Professionals</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Photo</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Video</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Motion</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 140px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

ul { 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1;
    top: 290px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10em;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px
}

a.btn1 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.3em 1.2em;
 margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
 border-radius: 2em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #4eb5f1;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
a.btn1:hover{
 background-color: #4095c6;
}
```

I appreciate any help or insight here.

I initially thought that it could be a browser issue, but I've seen nothing strange going on there. And have also tried this code with other browsers such as Firefox. Still the same issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after 'padding-right: 40px;' in your li CSS selector.  Not sure how much of a difference that will make.

Comment: Rectified, unfortunately, did not make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your css have unknow unicode in `a.btn` and `a.btn:hover`

**I replaced the front character with a blank space**

[image]

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 140px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

ul { 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1;
    top: 290px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10em;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px
}

a.btn1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  border-radius: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #4eb5f1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
a.btn1:hover{
  background-color: #4095c6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img style="width: 40%" src="https://i.imgur.com/wNLc5fC.jpg">
  <div>
    <h2>Digital Assets For Creative Professionals</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Photo</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Video</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="btn1">Motion</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incredible. This fixed the issue! Guess I need to read more about Unicodes!

Answer (score 0):

If the file css code is on another file make sure your link doesn't have syntax error, make sure also you saved the file before you load the page. I tried your code using the style tag on the html file and is working fine.